# Expected entropy on output of a random function, and of $F(x)=P(x)\oplus x$ with $P$ a random permutation

Tags: entropy, function

Let $F$ be a function on the set $\{0,1\}^n$ of $n$-bit vectors. Let $H_F$ be the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) (in bits) of the source $F(x)$ where $x$ is uniformly random. That is
$$\begin{align*}
H_F&=\sum_{y\in F(\{0,1\}^n)}-\operatorname{Prob}(F(x)=y)\;\log_2\big(\operatorname{Prob}(F(x)=y)\big)\\
\\
& = n-{1\over2^n}\;\sum_{y\in F(\{0,1\}^n)}\big(\#{\{x, F(x)=y)\}}\big)\;\log_2\big(\#{\{x, F(x)=y)\}}\big)
\\
& = n-{1\over2^n}\;\sum_{j=2}^{2^n}\big(\#{\{y,(\#\{x:F(x)=y\})=j\}}\big)\; j\;\log_2(j)
\end{align*}$$
Note: $\#{\{x, F(x)=y)\}}$ of the 2<sup>nd</sup> equation is the number of preimages of vector $y$; and $\#{\{y,(\#\{x:F(x)=y\})=j\}}$ of the 3<sup>rd</sup> is the number of vectors with exactly $j$ preimages.

Define $\mathcal H(n)$ as the expected $H_F$ when $F$ is uniformly random among the $(2^n)^{(2^n)}$ functions on $\{0,1\}^n$.

**How can we strengthen the argument (given below) that**
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n-\mathcal H(n)}\;=\eta={1\over e}\sum_{j=2}^\infty{j\;\log_2j\over j!}\;\;=0.8272454\dots\text{bit}$$

Define $\mathcal H_\oplus(n)$ as the expected $H_F$ when $\forall x, F(x)=P(x)\oplus x$ and $P$ is uniformly random among the $(2^n)!$ permutations of $\{0,1\}^n$ ( $\oplus$ is [bitwise exclusive-OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR)). Such $F$ are often used in cryptography with $P$ a pseudo-random permutation, e.g. in the [Davies-Meyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Davies.E2.80.93Meyer) construction, a close variant of which being used in hashes such as MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-2.

**How can we prove that the following $\eta_\oplus$ is well-defined, compare it to $\eta$, or compute it?**
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n-\mathcal H_\oplus(n)}\;=\eta_\oplus$$

Note: I asked essentially the second part [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/43442/555).
**Update:** that now has [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/43546/555), giving what I believe is a leak-free proof of both convergences, with $\eta_\oplus=\eta$. I now consider making a self-answer out of that.

---

My not-rigorous-enough argument for the derivation of the limit $\eta$ is based on the well established fact that $\forall j\ge0$, the expected value of $\big(\#{\{y,(\#\{x:F(x)=y\})=j\}}\big)/2^n$ for $F$ a random function converges to $1/(e\;j!)$ as $n\to\infty$. Replacing in the third equation for $H_F$, invoking I-wish-I-knew-which theorem and extra conditions, I get the desired convergence and limit. At least, randomized experiments confirm the result and value beyond doubt.

I've been unable to locate a reference; the closest I found is an empirical derivation of $\eta$ to 4 decimals by [Andrea Röck](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/secret/Andrea.Roeck/index.php): [*Collision Attacks based on the Entropy Loss caused by Random Functions*](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/secret/Andrea.Roeck/pdfs/wework_randFct.pdf#page=6), WEWoRC 2007, [slides](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/secret/Andrea.Roeck/pdfs/roeck_weworc.pdf#page=24); with more in her [thesis](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/secret/Andrea.Roeck/pdfs/these_roeck.pdf#page=102).